# How to convert spark dataframe[double , String] to LabeledPoint?

Tags: apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

Following is the code that am experimenting with. Am trying to convert SalesData in csv to DF and then to LabeledPoints. However in the last step am getting following compilation error

**package macros contains object and package with same name: blackbox**

Can you please give me pointers on what am doing wrong here ? Thank you

--EDIT--
Compilation Issue solved by adding 2.11 mllib to build.gradle . but mlData.show fails with

**ERROR:  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector**

```
    val path = "SalesData.csv"
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[2]").set("deploy-mode", "client").set("spark.driver.bindAddress", "127.0.0.1")
      .set("spark.broadcast.compress", "false")
      .setAppName("local-spark-kafka-consumer-client")
  val sparkSession = SparkSession
      .builder()
      .config(conf)
      .getOrCreate()
    val data = sparkSession.read.format("csv").option("header", "true").option("inferSchema", "true").load(path)
    data.cache()
    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameNaFunctions
    data.na.drop()
    data.show

    //get monthly sales totals 
    val summary = data.select("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount").groupBy("OrderMonthYear").sum().orderBy("OrderMonthYear").toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")
    summary.show

    // convert ordermonthyear to integer type
    //val results = summary.map(df => (df.getAs[String]("OrderMonthYear").replace("-", "") , df.getAs[String]("SaleAmount"))).toDF(["OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount"])
    import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
    val test = summary.withColumn("OrderMonthYear", (regexp_replace(col("OrderMonthYear").cast("String"),"-",""))).toDF("OrderMonthYear","SaleAmount")
    test.printSchema()
    test.show
    import sparkSession.implicits._
    val mlData = test.select("OrderMonthYear", "SaleAmount").
                  map(row => org.apache.spark.ml.feature.LabeledPoint(
                              row.getAs[Double](1),
                              row.getAs[org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector](0))).toDF
mlData.show
```